# Powershell connection string to SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

Hi I'm trying to execute a Powershell on my local PC however using data from a remote SQL server.

I have script like this. It's wrong because I haven't stated the username and password to log on to the server. Could anyone tell me the correct format of doing that?

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=10.10.1.34;Database=AMSDataWarehouseTest;user id=YQBGantt;password=123yqbgantt"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "YQBreport1"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$SQLResult =$DataSet.Tables[0]
$commands = $SQLResult | foreach-object -process { $_.output }> output.ps1
.\output.ps1
```

Comment: How do you know its wrong? If there is an error *please tell us what it is*. (I can see you have included the user name and password so that is clearly not the issue.)

Comment: Hi Richard, The username and password is for the database, not for the server. to be able to use the database on the server I think I need to include the log in to the server as well in the connection string somehow.

Comment: No you don't need to login to the server and then to SQL Server. You just log into SQL Server.

Comment: I tried with the connection string I have, it's not working, however, it's not throwing any error as well, the powershell window will just remain open all the time. Normally I access the server through VPN, would that be the problem?

Comment: In that case switch on tracing and find out where it is hanging (it might not be on connection, maybe that command is hanging): `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1`. **NB.** if the connection was failing due to authentication you would get an immediate error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this connection string instead:

```
Data Source=10.10.1.34;Initial Catalog=AMSDataWarehouseTest;uid=YQBGantt;pwd=123yqbgantt
```

Also, make sure the SQL Server is configured to [accept remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have a SQL Server instance 2012 named 'RegencyPark' on a laptop named 'Hodentek8'. These statements connect to my SQL Server and render it to open.

```
PS C:\Users\Jayaram> $ConnectionString="Server=Hodentek8\RegencyPark;database=AdventureWorks2012;trusted_connection=true;"

PS C:\Users\Jayaram> $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection($ConnectionString)

PS C:\Users\Jayaram> $Connection.Open()

PS C:\Users\Jayaram> $Connection.State
Open
```